# Raspberry Pi Coffee Maker

Tags: coffee-machines

Has anyone here made their own Coffee Maker?  I have a rapsberry pi and I am looking into making a coffee maker out of it.  Potentially it would be a drip of some sort, but I am unsure what to do.  I am looking for some inspiration and help in a general direction.  If you were make your own "ultimate coffee maker", what would it do?

Comment: I also want to add to my thought / comment, that I would like to see a grinder with it.  I have now seen some examples where you preload ground bean and it heats it up for you.  Its basically a RaspberryPi or Arduino Coffee brewer.  But I am thinking more.  Something that senses  the cup size, will grind the beans, measure (weight) and then dispense, brew, pour.  I haven't seen any "automated DIY" grinders yet.